# How to remove key error from the program?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

[In the image you can see that i have ID still getting key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlrAe.png) I am trying to do a recommendation algorithm so i got this error

```
 #the first argument in the below function to be passed is the id of the book, second argument is the number of books you want to be recommended#

    KeyError: <built-in function id>
```

I am sharing link of article https://towardsdatascience.com/recommender-engine-under-the-hood-7869d5eab072

```
      import pandas as pd
      from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
      from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
      ds = pd.read_csv("test1.csv") #you can plug in your own list of products or movies or books here as csv file#
      tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')

#ngram explanation begins#
#ngram (1,3) can be explained as follows#
#ngram(1,3) encompasses uni gram, bi gram and tri gram
#consider the sentence "The ball fell"
#ngram (1,3) would be the, ball, fell, the ball, ball fell, the ball fell
#ngram explanation ends#

      tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['Book Title'])
      cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
      results = {} # dictionary created to store the result in a dictionary format (ID : 
      (Score,item_id))#
      for idx, row in ds.iterrows(): #iterates through all the rows

# the below code 'similar_indice' stores similar ids based on cosine similarity. sorts them in ascending 
      order. [:-5:-1] is then used so that the indices with most similarity are got. 0 means no similarity and 1 means perfect similarity#
      similar_indices = cosine_similarities[idx].argsort()[:-5:-1] 

    #stores 5 most similar books, you can change it as per your needs
     similar_items = [(cosine_similarities[idx][i], ds['ID'][i]) for i in similar_indices]
     results[row['ID']] = similar_items[1:]

#below code 'function item(id)' returns a row matching the id along with Book Title. Initially it is a dataframe, then we convert it to a list#
      def item(id):
         return ds.loc[ds['ID'] == id]['Book Title'].tolist()[0]
      def recommend(id, num):
          if (num == 0):
           print("Unable to recommend any book as you have not chosen the number of book to be 
    recommended")
        elif (num==1):
          print("Recommending " + str(num) + " book similar to " + item(id))

        else :
           print("Recommending " + str(num) + " books similar to " + item(id))

       print("----------------------------------------------------------")
          recs = results[id][:num]
             for rec in recs:
                print("You may also like to read: " + item(rec[1]) + " (score:" + str(rec[0]) + ")")

#the first argument in the below function to be passed is the id of the book, second argument is the number of books you want to be recommended#
        recommend(5,2)
```

i have try and run successfully till results variable then getting error.

Answer (score 1):

because python default id keyword is called when you call "def item(id):"
instead of id you have to declare another identifier....then i think this is the only reason for keyerror..

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests id is an build-in function in python-3. So if you change the name of the parameters id in `def item(id)` and `def recommend(id, num)` and all their references then the code should work.

After changing the id and correcting the indentation, an example could look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

ds = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")  # you can plug in your own list of products or movies or books here as csv file
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')

# ngram explanation begins#
# ngram (1,3) can be explained as follows#
# ngram(1,3) encompasses uni gram, bi gram and tri gram
# consider the sentence "The ball fell"
# ngram (1,3) would be the, ball, fell, the ball, ball fell, the ball fell
# ngram explanation ends#

tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['Book Title'])
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
results = {}  # dictionary created to store the result in a dictionary format (ID : (Score,item_id))

for idx, row in ds.iterrows():  # iterates through all the rows

    # the below code 'similar_indice' stores similar ids based on cosine similarity. sorts them in ascending 
    # order. [:-5:-1] is then used so that the indices with most similarity are got. 0 means no similarity and 
    # 1 means perfect similarity
    similar_indices = cosine_similarities[idx].argsort()[:-5:-1]

    # stores 5 most similar books, you can change it as per your needs
    similar_items = [(cosine_similarities[idx][i], ds['ID'][i]) for i in similar_indices]
    results[row['ID']] = similar_items[1:]


# below code 'function item(id)' returns a row matching the id along with Book Title. Initially it is a dataframe, 
# then we convert it to a list#
def item(ID):
    return ds.loc[ds['ID'] == ID]['Book Title'].tolist()[0]


def recommend(ID, num):
    if num == 0:
        print("Unable to recommend any book as you have not chosen the number of book to be recommended")
    elif num == 1:
        print("Recommending " + str(num) + " book similar to " + item(ID))

    else:
        print("Recommending " + str(num) + " books similar to " + item(ID))

    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    recs = results[ID][:num]
    for rec in recs:
        print("You may also like to read: " + item(rec[1]) + " (score:" + str(rec[0]) + ")")


# the first argument in the below function to be passed is the id of the book, second argument is the number of books 
# you want to be recommended
recommend(5, 2)
```

Comment: I try but still getting error ID not found
def item(ID):
    return ds.loc[ds['ID'] == ID]['Book Title'].tolist()[0]
def recommend(ID, num):
    if (num == 0):
        print("Unable to recommend any book as you have not chosen the number of book to be recommended")
    elif (num==1):
        print("Recommending " + str(num) + " book similar to " + item(ID))
        else :
        print("Recommending " + str(num) + " books similar to " + item(ID))
        recs = results[ID][:num]

Comment: Are you sure your indents are correct because I cannot see if they are in the right order from your pasted code? For Python, it is crutial to indent your code correctly.

Comment: I attach the image in my question you can see that if you can help me in the code term?

Comment: As I thought is your code not indented correctly. For instance, the code snippet recs = results[ID][:num] should be indented into the def recommed block because then you can access id and num.